# Converting serialized data in array to string in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am pulling data from a field in MySQL. The field is pulling images in the form of a a serialized string from an API. The API delivers the following data to the "images" column in MySQL.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:87:"http://url/image.jpg";i:1;s:85:"http://url/image2.jpg";}
```

If `print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` I get an output of :

```
[  
 {  
  "title":"Product 1",
  "images":"a:2{i:0;s:87:\"http://url/image1.jpg";i:1;s:85:\"http://url/image2.jpg";}"
 }
]
```

What I am trying to get back is just

```
[  
 {  
  "title":"Product 2",
  "images":[  
   "http://url/image1.jpg",
   "http://url/image2.jpg"
  ]
 }
]
```

I'm not sure how to unserialize the "images" key into a separated common list. I have tried `unserialize()` function in different forms, with no dice. 
Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unserialize()` function:

```
$ary = json_decode($json);


for($i=0; $i < count($ary['images']); $i++){
   $ary['images'][$i] = unserialize($ary['images'][$i]);
}


$obj = json_encode($ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string represents an array, in serialized form. You would need to unserialize it first. The problem is that your string, as provided, isn't a valid serialized data. It looks like it should resolve to

```
$images = array("http://url/image1.jpg", "http://url/image2.jpg");
```

To get your desired output you would need an array that looks like this

```
$data = array(
     'title' => 'Product 1',
     'images' => $images
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about accessing the data in the 'images' key so that I can make it into an $images array?

Comment: Normally you'd do `unserialize('your serialized data here');` but the string in your question won't unserialize